# How to insert multiple rows or say post JSON ARRAY using spring data rest MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-rest

I am using spring data rest-mongodb with spring boot. We need to make a post request in order to save entry in db. But this is not working when i try to insert multiple rows or say when using JSON array and instead giving error as below:Can not deserialize instance of com.collections.User out of START_ARRAY token.

Comment: Can you please post the code that you have tried. It would help seek more attention.

Comment: yes, i tried posting my code, but stackoverflow is not allowing me to do it and instead giving me error as the code is not properly formatted.

Comment: @BatScream: It ll be very helpful, if you can provide any example for inserting multiple rows using spring data rest.